# Error on 'foreman start' while following the Python/Flask Heroku tutorial

Tags: ruby, heroku, foreman

Followed all instructions. Get this error when running `foreman start`:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.47.0/lib/fo reman/engine.rb:39:in `trap': unsupported signal SIGHUP (ArgumentError)
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.47.0/lib/foreman/engine.rb:39:in `start'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.47.0/lib/foreman/cli.rb:34:in `start'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.3/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.3/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.3/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.47.0/bin/foreman:7:in `<top (required)>'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/foreman:19:in `load'
       from C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/foreman:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what do you have in your `Procfile`?

Comment: What I should, according to the tutorial.

web: python app.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem and solved it, I think it should solve your issue too (be sure to uninstall former installations of ruby as sometimes there are several installations of the same version). Here is the solution: [Foreman start fails on Windows following Heroku tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434287/foreman-start-fails-on-windows-following-heroku-tuturial/11436332#11436332)

Answer (score 3):

So, apparently `foreman` does not work on Windows, which was not mentioned in the Heroku tutorial. Hope they fix that.

Comment: @Rosarch - I was able to use foreman on windows, look at the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434287/foreman-start-fails-on-windows-following-heroku-tuturial/11436332#11436332 , So I guess their support guys are not updated.

Comment: this answer is incorrect. foreman is a ruby app, so you need to install ruby first. see the link zenpoy provided.